# SQL - How to sum revenue by customer over the last 7 days for each date

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to sum the previous 7 days revenue from each date for each customer. There are some missing dates for some customers and various different customers so I cannot use a Lag function. I was previously using windows but I could only partition by customer_ID and could not partition by the date range as well.

Some sample data as follows:

| Customer_ID | Date | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/02/21 | $20 |
| 2 | 01/02/21 | $30 |
| 1 | 02/02/21 | $40 |
| 2 | 02/02/21 | $50 |
| 1 | 03/02/21 | $20 |
| 2 | 03/02/21 | $60 |
| 1 | 04/02/21 | $10 |
| 2 | 04/02/21 | $80 |
| 1 | 05/02/21 | $100 |
| 2 | 05/02/21 | $40 |
| 1 | 06/02/21 | $20 |
| 2 | 06/02/21 | $30 |
| 1 | 07/02/21 | $50 |
| 2 | 07/02/21 | $70 |
| 1 | 08/02/21 | $10 |
| 2 | 08/02/21 | $20 |
| 1 | 09/02/21 | $3 |
| 2 | 09/02/21 | $40 |

This result would give the sum of the previous seven days revenue broken down by customer ID for each date. It is ordered by Customer_ID and Date

| Customer_ID | Date | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/02/21 | $20 |
| 1 | 02/02/21 | $60 |
| 1 | 03/02/21 | $80 |
| 1 | 04/02/21 | $90 |
| 1 | 05/02/21 | $190 |
| 1 | 06/02/21 | $210 |
| 1 | 07/02/21 | $260 |
| 1 | 08/02/21 | $250 |
| 1 | 09/02/21 | $240 |
| 2 | 01/02/21 | $30 |
| 2 | 02/02/21 | $80 |
| 2 | 03/02/21 | $140 |
| 2 | 04/02/21 | $220 |
| 2 | 05/02/21 | $260 |
| 2 | 06/02/21 | $290 |
| 2 | 07/02/21 | $360 |
| 2 | 08/02/21 | $350 |
| 2 | 09/02/21 | $340 |

Data:
[Database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XK8X.png)

Query Result:
[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsNla.png)

Answer (score 1):

select customer_id,date,sum(revenue) from customer_table where date >= sysdate-7 and date < =sysdate group by customer_id,date;

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

You can try going with a self join, where you match on:

- tab1.customer_id = table2.customer_id
- tab1.date being matched with till-6-days-before records of tab2.date.

Then apply the `SUM` on t2.revenues and aggregate on the selected fields.

```
SELECT t1.Customer_ID, 
       t1.Date,
       SUM(t2.Revenue) AS total
FROM      tab t1 
LEFT JOIN tab t2
       ON t1.Customer_ID = t2.Customer_ID
      AND t1.Date BETWEEN t2.Date AND DATEADD(day, -6, t2.Date)
GROUP BY t1.Customer_ID, 
         t1.Date
```

This approach would avoid the issue of missing dates for customers, as long as you are comparing dates instead of taking the "last 7 records" with `LAG`.

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte as (-- Customer_ID Date    Revenue
 select 1 customer_id,  DATE( '01/02/2021','DD/MM/YYYY')  Some_date,     20 Revenue 
union all select 2 customer_id, DATE( '01/02/2021','DD/MM/YYYY') Some_date,  30 Revenue 
union all select 1 customer_id, DATE( '03/02/2021','DD/MM/YYYY') Some_date,  20 Revenue 
union all select 2 customer_id, DATE( '03/02/2021','DD/MM/YYYY') Some_date,  60 Revenue 
union all select 1 customer_id, DATE( '04/02/2021','DD/MM/YYYY') Some_date,  10 Revenue 
union all select 2 customer_id, DATE( '04/02/2021','DD/MM/YYYY') Some_date,  80 Revenue 
union all select 1 customer_id, DATE( '05/02/2021','DD/MM/YYYY') Some_date,  100 Revenue 
union all select 2 customer_id, DATE( '05/02/2021','DD/MM/YYYY') Some_date,  40 Revenue 
union all select 1 customer_id, DATE( '06/02/2021','DD/MM/YYYY') Some_date,  20 Revenue 
union all select 2 customer_id, DATE( '06/02/2021','DD/MM/YYYY') Some_date,  30 Revenue 
union all select 1 customer_id, DATE( '07/02/2021','DD/MM/YYYY') Some_date,  50 Revenue 
union all select 2 customer_id, DATE( '07/02/2021','DD/MM/YYYY') Some_date,  70 Revenue 
union all select 1 customer_id, DATE( '08/02/2021','DD/MM/YYYY') Some_date,  10 Revenue 
union all select 2 customer_id, DATE( '08/02/2021','DD/MM/YYYY') Some_date,  20 Revenue 
union all select 1 customer_id, DATE( '09/02/2021','DD/MM/YYYY') Some_date,  3 Revenue
union all select 1 customer_id, DATE( '02/02/2021','DD/MM/YYYY') Some_date,  40 Revenue 
union all select 2 customer_id, DATE( '02/02/2021','DD/MM/YYYY') Some_date,  50   Revenue 
union all select 2 customer_id, DATE( '09/02/2021','DD/MM/YYYY') Some_date,  40 Revenue)

 select customer_id, revenue
  , DATE_TRUNC('week', Some_date )  week_number 
  , sum(revenue) 
    over(partition by customer_id,week_number 
    order by Some_date asc 
    rows between unbounded preceding and current row) volia
 from cte
```

[image]